# Differences in the usage of “Hang around” in the following sentences?

Tags: grammar

what are the differences between these sentences?

1. > He is hanging around on the streets
2. > He is hanging around the streets

and

1. > He is hanging around at the mall
2. > He is hanging around the mall

Answer (score 1):

There is not much of a difference in each case and would likely achieve the same level of understanding by anyone.

Number 1 in each case is more specific and can be understood as someone being *exactly* on the streets and *exactly* at the mall. Whereas number 2 in each case is more subjective. For example he could be around the mall, in the mall, or just outside.

Answer (score 0):

1. > He is hanging around on the streets

is clearly understood as:

1. > He (is hanging around) (on the streets)

as in:

> He is just wasting some time on the streets.

---

3. > He is hanging around at the mall

is clearly understood as:

3. > He (is hanging around) (at the mall)

as in:

> He is just wasting some time at the mall.

---

BUT:

2. > He is hanging around the streets

is understood more like:

2. > He is hanging (around the streets)

as in: he definitely avoids walking on the street. Question: who will understand what from "is hanging"?

---

Same for:

4. > He is hanging around the mall

is understood more like:

4. > He is hanging (around the mall)

as in: he does not enter the mall. Question: who will understand what from "is hanging"?

---

The bottom line is, if you spare words, the meaning will be lost or, even worse, understood wrong.